# Exporting an SQL database batch file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

```
sqlcmd -S LAPTOP-C8OQQD9E\WASPDBEXPRESS -d WaspTime -U sa -P xxxxxxxx -Q "select * from WaspTime.dbo.employee" -o "MyData.csv"
```

I need to change this so it'll export the full database. How would I do that?

Comment: You write a very, VERY complicated script if you intend to do this without hardcoding names. Or you generate a backup. Without more detail about your goal, it is difficult to say much more.

Comment: My boss wants full access to the database in an excel file. I figured exported it into a csv file would work best.

Comment: This isn't a `batch-file` code problem.

Answer (score 0):

> My boss wants full access to the database in an excel file

Then use [Power Pivot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/power-pivot-overview-and-learning-f9001958-7901-4caa-ad80-028a6d2432ed) in Excel to import one or more tables into an embedded data model.  Much simpler and more efficient than exporting to .CSV.

[image]

Comment: I might have to go this route. I'd prefer to stick to a batch file. I don't want to be tied down to a program that might not be installed.